# Rotate camera in function of direction of ball

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm making a maze whit Unity3D where a ball can roll and find the out way. Because the ball can be hide after a wall, I want to rotate the camera to a better position in function of the direction of the ball.

Take this example: the ball is rolling in to you (in the direction of the black arrow). So you <strike>can see or beter</strike> can't see, is where the ball is rolling to. So the camera must turn to the other side of the ball. If the ball rolls away from you must the camera turn to the original location.

[image: situation of ball where you can't see where the ball is rolling to]

The problem is now, I know how I can replace the camera but not in function of the direction? Can anyone help me with this? I'm just starting with Unity3D. Language behind I use C#.

Here is another situation where it is better to rotate the camera. (up: is scene, below game mode).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to set the camera position behind the ball based on the velocity and then the rotation in the direction of the ball

```
Vector3 offset = new Vector3(1,1,0);
transform.position = ball.transform.position - ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity / ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude + offset;
transform.LookAt (ball.transform.position);
```

Comment: For less motion sickness, maybe this could be set as a curve target for the camera, rather than something that's set immediately?

Comment: Not exactly what I will, I will that the camera can turn 360°. With your code, it is that not possible.

Comment: I've also this error: `transform.position assign attempt for 'Main Camera' is not valid. Input position is { NaN, NaN, NaN }.` on 2nd line of you code.

Comment: I tested this code and it run well without any error. I don't understand what you want to say with the 360º can you explain better.

Comment: @Luïs I think the word you want is "want", not "will". Can you elaborate why you believe that this will not rotate the camera in any direction?

Comment: @Katana314: oké, I was totally wrong. My excuses :-s